# Scroll hangs in Collection view when SectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds is used in Xamarin Forms for iOS platform

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a simple collection view with grouping set to True, and wanted the group header to be sticky on top. So, for that I have created custom layout for Collection View and used the property **"SectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = True"**.

But once I set it to true my scroll of collection view starts hanging.

CustomCollectionView in iOS

namespace CollectionViewTest.iOS
{
public class CustomCollectionViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CollectionViewRenderer
{
public CustomCollectionViewRenderer()
{
}

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<GroupableItemsView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var view = Control as UIView;
            var uiCollectionView = view.Subviews.FirstOrDefault(a => a is UICollectionView);
            if (uiCollectionView is UICollectionView collectionView)
            {
                if (collectionView.CollectionViewLayout is UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout)
                {
                    layout.SectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

How can I make this scroll smooth with using sticky headers.

Xamarin Forms v5.0

Platform - iOS

Device - iPhone 12 iOS 15.2

Control - CollectionView

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://github.com/xamcat/Scratch/blob/master/FormsStickyHeaders/FormsStickyHeaders.iOS/Renderers/StickyHeaderCollectionViewRenderer.cs) which implement the function that you want.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - Mentioned file is not rendering in POC, they have another file in Controls folder which have the same code I have mentioned in question. And by using the same property scroll is not smooth on iPhone devices. Please let me know if you have any other idea.

Comment: Also if you can see the reference Videos provided in the demo link having the same problem with iPhone.

Comment: Same issue there, reported https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15161